# 'Unsafe call of an `any` typed value' for middleware function call

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm calling a middleware function for browser support like so:

```
app.get(
      "/*",
      checkBrowserSupport(
        shared.browserStatuses,
        shared.browserSupport.supportedBrowsers,
        {
          unsupported: shared.paths.browserUnsupported,
          denied: shared.paths.browserDenied,
        }
      ),
      (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).type("html").send(indexHTML);
      }
    );
  }
```

The actual function looks like so:

```
export function checkBrowserSupport(
  browserStatuses: string[],
  supportedBrowsers: ISupportedBrowser[],
  paths: IPath
) {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   ...
  };
}
```

VSCode has a squiggly under the call and the warning: 'Unsafe call of an `any` typed value'

Do I need to add a return type? I'm not even sure what type I'd add.

Comment: "VSCode has a squiggly under the call" - ...under *which* call?

Comment: checkBrowserSupport in the app.get

Comment: Then it sounds like that `checkBrowserSupport` is `any`-typed for some reason...

Comment: It seems TS should be able to infer the type of `checkBrowserSupport`. Are you sure this is even a TypeScript warning? To me that sounds like a message from my linter (which often enough fails to keep up with the type defintions).

Comment: I just got ahold of a co-worker and it was a config issue with our project that was added recently. Thanks for the help!